# Can't adjust column width in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader, preferredsize

I  am  testing table model and render. But I faced some problem in adjusting column width, I can't adjust column width as it's content text. I used JWindow and hide JFrame .I want to adjust column width of this table as I like........
but I can't though I used this code.......

```
for(int i=0;i<header.length;i++){
        TableColumn col=table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        if(i==0)
            col.setWidth(106);
        if(i==1)
            col.setWidth(157);
        if(i==2)
            col.setWidth(103);
        if(i==3)
            col.setWidth(103);
    }
```

this is my whole code ....check this...pls...........

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class ReportDamage extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private static JTable table = new JTable();
    private String[] header = { "Damage_Id", "Supplier_Stock_Id", "Quantity",
            "Date" };
    private String[][] data = null;
    private DefaultTableModel table_model = new TableModel();
    private static JLabel move;
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    private static JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    private JPanel bpanel=new JPanel();
    static Window container = f;
    static JWindow window = new JWindow(container);
    private JPanel bar=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    private JLabel title=new JLabel("Damage Table");
    static Point windowp, mouse, movep;
    private boolean flag=false;

    public ReportDamage() throws SQLException {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        table.setModel(table_model);
        table.setRowHeight(25);
        table.getTableHeader().setFont(
                new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
        table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(24, 36, 233));
        table.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        //table.getTableHeader().setEnabled(false);
        table.setFont(new Font("Zawgyi-One", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,
                (TableCellRenderer) new Renderer());
        for(int i=0;i<header.length;i++){
            TableColumn col=table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if(i==0)
                col.setWidth(106);
            if(i==1)
                col.setWidth(157);
            if(i==2)
                col.setWidth(103);
            if(i==3)
                col.setWidth(103);
        }
        scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white,3),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
        scroll.setBackground(Color.white);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(
                        new listener(),
                        AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
                                | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        move = new JLabel("+");
        move.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 19));
        move.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                flag=false;
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                flag=true;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        ok.setForeground(Color.black);
        ok.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 17));
        ok.setBackground(new Color(33, 33, 250));
        ok.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 18, 5, 18)));
        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                f.dispose();
                for(int i=0;i<header.length;i++){
                TableColumn col=table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
                    System.out.println(col.getWidth()+ " width of col "+ i);
                }
            }
        });

        ok.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ok.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(),
                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 18, 5, 18)));
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ok.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1),
                        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 18, 5, 18)));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ok.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ok.setForeground(Color.white);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        GridBagLayout gbb = (GridBagLayout) getLayout();
        GridBagConstraints cb = new GridBagConstraints();

        cb.fill=0;cb.gridwidth=1;
        gbb.setConstraints(move, cb);
        add(move);
        gbb.setConstraints(title, cb);
        add(title);


        title.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,18));
        //fillTable();

        GridBagLayout gb = (GridBagLayout) getLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        bpanel.add(ok);
        c.fill = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 0;
        gb.setConstraints(bar, c);
        add(bar);
        gb.setConstraints(scroll, c);
        add(scroll);
        gb.setConstraints(bpanel,c);
        add(bpanel);

        title.setForeground(Color.white);
        title.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4,9,15,0));
        move.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-5,0,35,15));
        move.setForeground(Color.white);
        bpanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        ok.setEnabled(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray,3),BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1)));
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    private void fillTable() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Statement st = (Statement) sqlCloseOrOpen.connect().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery("Select * from damage");

        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        String[] array = new String[4];
        while (rs.next()) {
            array[0] = rs.getInt(1) + "";
            array[1] = rs.getInt(2) + "";
            array[2] = rs.getInt(3) + "";
            array[3] = rs.getString(4);
            tm.addRow(array);
        }

    }

    public static void showGUI() throws SQLException {

        window.getContentPane().removeAll();
        window.getContentPane().add(new ReportDamage());
        // f.setResizable(false);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.pack();
         container.pack();
        // f.setContentPane(new ReportDamage());
        window.setOpacity(.8f);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setLocation(140, 150);
        window.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        showGUI();
    }

    public class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        Renderer() {
            super();
            setOpaque(true);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {

            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                    hasFocus, row, column);

            int r = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (row == r) {
                setBackground(new Color(110, 40, 40));
                setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
            } else {
                setForeground(Color.black);
                setFont(new Font("Zawgyi-One", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                if (row % 2 == 0) {
                    setBackground(new Color(223, 223, 223));
                } else {
                    setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                }
            }

            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);

            return this;
        }
    }

    public class listener implements AWTEventListener {

        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (arg0.paramString().startsWith("MOUSE_DRAGGED")&& flag==true) {
                windowp = window.getLocation();
                movep = move.getLocation();
                mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                window.setLocation((mouse.x - movep.x) - 5,
                        (mouse.y - movep.y) - 10);
            }

        }

    }

    public class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel{

        TableModel(){
            super(data, header);
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row ,int column){

            return false;
        }       

    }

}
```

`

Comment: Try using `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);` before you change the size of the columns.  You could also try using `setPreferredWidth` instead of `setWidth`

Comment: Got it...setPreferredWidth...it is work!.....thanks....